# Why does this program not do anything with throw?

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGYPs.png)

I am reading some code online for a function and it has this throw-sentence.

I implemented the same function, but when I call it to make sure it throws (by making  x negative), my code doesn't work, because I am not "handling the exception".

But neither does the code in the picture, so what's going on here?

Basically what I am looking for is a function that gets called when somebody inputs bad arguments to a function, and then the function just halts the program and says "no you're doing it wrong". How do I do that?

I read online a bit about throw and catch and try and all that, but really, I don't want to do that. I just want ONE thing to halt the program once it sences something is wrong.

Comment: You can't know that the code you looked at isn't handling the exception, because exception handling is suppose to happen further down the call stack. It depends on where and how it's called.

Comment: Please provide [mcve], as text, in the question itself.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why does there need to be "exception handling"? Isn't that unnecessary amount of work? Why isn't there a simple function that just halts and throws an appropiate error that is readable? If that function is not "throw", then what it is? I am looking for a function that just halts a program when a condition is met and gives a readable error. That sounds like a super-useful thing. Is the only way to achieve that in C++ via some verbose try catch throw machinery?

Comment: @jansai I don't know what makes you think catching exceptions is verbose. You just need a `try`, a `catch` and a `std::cerr` output in `main`. That's 3 *very* short and clear lines. I guess 4 if `catch` isn't the last thing in your `main` and you need to `return`. If you want to exit on the spot, you can `std::cerr` and `std::terminate` wherever you are. If can even put those two lines in a short named function if brevity is very important.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to generate some message (e.g. in console output) only you can simlpy to modify the first condition: remove throw, add output to std::cout and return some value (e.g. 0). I.e. replace

```
if (x < 0.0 || a <= 0.0) throw("bad args in gammq");
```

by

```
if (x < 0.0 || a <= 0.0)
{
   std::cout << "bad args in gammq";
   return 0.;
}
```

But that means you need to check the result of function for possibility to use it since 0 means error now. Otherwise you can join the computations into try block and catch exceptions of this block. And it's more accurate to generate exception of std::invalid_argument for the case. So condition:

```
if (x < 0.0 || a <= 0.0) throw("bad args in gammq");
```

is better to modify to

```
if (x < 0.0 || a <= 0.0) throw std::invalid_argument("bad args in gammq");
```

Please remeber to

```
#include <stdexcept>
```

which defines std::invalid_argument. And usage is:

```
try
{
   Doub a,x;
   // some computations and initialization of a and x
   Doub val = gammq(a,x);
   // some other computations
}
catch(std::invalid_argument& e)
{
   std::cout << e.what();
}
```

As soon as gammq receives wrong argument the computation inside try block will be terminated and catch block will generate message in console output.